# Can I run my win7 on another machine with different motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, motherboard

I want to have my system with me in another city. I know that it strongly depends of my chipset. I have P35 (Gigabyte P35DS3R). Another machine also Intel-based but chipset is G31 (MSI G31TM-P35). Is it possible that my system will start on that machine when I plug in my hdd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 will be aware that the hardware has changed and will ask you to call an automated 1-800 number to verify and re-activate your Windows installation and again on your return when you plug your HDD back into your current system.

**Always remember**
Microsoft can and will limit your number of activations, eventually making it more and more difficult to re-activate. I wouldn't recommend switching on a regular basis.

Comment: And again on your return when you plug your hdd back into your current system.

Comment: @ChrisF - Thanks and good point... added to my answer

Comment: And at any point, if they feel like it, they can say you're trying to activate too many copies with your key and refuse to let you activate it.

Comment: Yes, this is also true. I was going to put that disclaimer in my original answer. I'll do that now.